# ssh-agent not starting in OpenSuSE desktop

Tags: ssh, opensuse, startup, ssh-agent

It seems that ssh-agent is not starting on my OpenSuSE system. When I run `pgrep -fl ssh-agent`, the result is blank. On my Linux Mint laptop, I get `1785 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session x-session-manager`.

How do I fix this? Can anyone with OpenSuSE check to see if it's not started up by default, or if I maybe messed something up?

#### things tried...

I've tried adding the following to `.xinitrc`,

```
if test -S "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" -a -x "$SSH_ASKPASS"; then
      ssh-add < /dev/null
fi
```

and my `.xsession` file contains,

```
ssh-agent {
  ssh-add &
  startkde
}
```

but neither of these things seems to do anything. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I have this same issue on my KDE only machines. Other openSUSE machines running XFCE or GNOME have no issue and this service is automatically started, except for KDE. I would like to hear of your fix if you find one.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so yesterday I installed the new 12.2RC2 ("GM") and 12.1 on separate partitions, both using KDE.

After I upgraded everything to the latest packages and enabled the SSHD service, I restarted and generated a private/public key pair with `ssh-keygen`

On both machines the sshd was running - but `ssh-add` output an error about not being able to connect to authorization agent or something.

So I ran `ssh-agent -k` where the -k flag "killed" the current running agent and then re-ran `ssh-agent` to restart it.

Then I restarted the PCs (*you might be able to just restart the sshd service instead*) and it was working! I could then issue `ssh-add` without any errors.

It looks like on KDE desktops ssh-agent is not initialized properly when you first start the sshd service, it works fine on other DE like GNOME or XFCE.